# Define priority for event handler with CKEDITOR.config.on

Tags: javascript, event-handling, ckeditor

we need to do some special processing for handling the 'toHtml' event of CKEditor.
We need to do this processing with data in the original string format, so we have to set a low priority (like 1). 
We can do this with the following:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editorName.on( 'toHtml', toHtmlHandler, null, null, 1 );
```

But we have tons of possible instances depending on the page, so we are trying to use this approach to do it only once:

```
configuration.on = {
    toHtml: toHtmlHandler
}
```

The problem with this is that we cannot figure out how to set priority in this form, is that   possible at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to set priority this way. Attach the listener within another listener (prior to `toHtml`):

```
function toHtmlHandler( evt ) {
    console.log( 'toHtml event', evt );
}

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function () {
            this.on( 'toHtml', toHtmlHandler, null, null, 1 );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Great, we followed this approach but handling the "instanceLoaded " event, thanks @oleq.

Comment: Use [`instanceCreated`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceCreated) instead of [`instanceLoaded`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceLoaded). Otherwise you lose the initial `toHtml` (when data comes from textarea), fired before `instanceLoaded`.